# Define function that takes string value, searches for it in dataframe column, and returns TRUE if it is in the column and contains the word "Sales"

Tags: python, pandas

I have to define a function called isSales() that takes the job title of an employee as a string and returns **True** if the job title indicates that the person works in Sales and returns **False** otherwise.

For this problem, I've created a dataframe(df) from reading an excel spreadsheet called "Employees". I then defined a function called employees() that takes the "Employees" Dataframe and sets the index to the "EmployeeID" column.

So, what I need the isSales() function to do is take the argument "jobtitle" and then search for this "jobtitle" in the "JobTitle" column of the "Employees" Dataframe.

What I have so far:

```
def isSales(jt):
    df1=load_employees(df)
    
    if df1.iloc[jt] in df1[df1["JobTitle"].apply(lambda x: 'Sales' in x)]:
            print("True")
    else: 
            print("False")
```

However, when I try to test this function out, the only result I get is **False**

```
isSales('Sales Representative')
```

Returns **False**

So, in defining the function IsSales(), what am I doing wrong?

I have a couple of other problems like this one where I am defining functions that search through the "Employees" dataframe. I think my issue is not fully understanding how to create functions that use pandas.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when writing Pandas code, you should avoid row-by-row iteration unless you have no choice. This is a situation where you have a choice.

Rather than calling your isSales function on each row, I would suggest using the builtin [Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

I would create a new column called IsSales, like this:

```py
df1["IsSales"] = df1["JobTitle"].str.contains("Sales", regex=False)
```

(The `regex=False` part is because this function will interpret your search as a regex by default.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Unfortunately, I have to create the isSales function. The problem states that the function should take the argument jobtitle (str) and return True or False.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why you're searching the dataframe at all, then. Isn't the function you're looking for just `def isSales(jt): return 'Sales' in jt` ? Why is the dataframe used at all?